# scl execution terminates bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to automate a reinstallation of a Centos box with a script, and everything is working well except that when `scl` is executed, the script terminates.

I use it to change the default g++ compiler to 8.

```
scl enable devtoolset-8 bash
```

How can I run scl without exiting my script?

Answer (score 2):

For RHEL, use:

```
source /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/enable
```

The script *enable* simply sets environment variables like `PATH`, `MANPATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, etc. so that the `devtoolset-8` tools are used instead of those that are installed to default paths. It is functionally similar to *scl enable* but it will not terminate your script.

Comment: Can you say a little about how to use this and how/why it works? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.